# Dynamic javascript select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

This was interesting.  In a select dropdown, trying not to use jQuery (with the exception of easing some of my pain on recreation), I ran into an issue that doesn't properly let any current browsers catch the proper selected option.  Here is my code, for the page that recreates the issue (remember, no jQuery to necessarily solve issue, but more or less just telling me what I am doing wrong.

This one has me stumped.

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="select-holder" />
<input id="some-button" type="button">

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#some-button").click(function(){

    var select_element = document.createElement('select');
    select_element.setAttribute("id", "some-id");
    select_element.setAttribute("name", "some-name");

    var options = new Array();
    for ( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
        options.push(new Option("Option " + i, "Value" + i, false, false));
    }
    options[1].setAttribute("selected", "selected");

    for ( var option in options ){
        select_element.appendChild(options[option]);
    }

    $("#select-holder").append(select_element);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The html this creates is:

```
    <select id="some-id" name="some-name">
    <option value="Value0">Option 0</option>
    <option value="Value1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Value2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

But the anomaly here is that (in firefox at least), the selected option ends up being Option 0, which isn't the selected DOM element.  In IE6, this select dropdown doesn't work at all.

There is an alternate method that does work, which includes piecing the options together manually, which works in all browsers that I have tested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A small change made it work for me in Firefox:

```
...
//options[1].setAttribute("selected", "selected");
options[1].selected = true;
...
```

I'm manipulating the DOM element's attributes directly. Not sure why your method doesn't work. Maybe you should keep both lines so that the HTML generated has the `selected = "selected"` in it.

Comment: IE6 doesn't work, but not sure I care.  If you have any suggestions for IE6 though, I would appreciate.  This worked perfectly in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

some old thread - however try something like this:

```
var idx=0;
while(obj.options[idx]) {
  if(obj.options[idx].value==value) obj.options[idx].setAttribute('selected',true);
  else  obj.options[idx].removeAttribute('selected');
  idx++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use selectedIndex to set the selected index of a select object.
`options.selectedIndex = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code, which seems like more of a Hack!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="select-holder" />
<input id="some-button" type="button">

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#some-button").click(function(){

    var select_element = document.createElement('select');
    select_element.setAttribute("id", "some-id");
    select_element.setAttribute("name", "some-name");


    for ( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
        var option_element = document.createElement('option');
        option_element.setAttribute('value', "Value" + i);
        option_element.appendChild( document.createTextNode( "Option " + i ) );
        if (i == 1){
            option_element.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
        }
        select_element.appendChild(option_element);
    }

    $("#select-holder").append(select_element);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
options[1].setAttribute("selected", "selected");
```

is likely where your issue lies. The output you're getting is:

```
<option value="Value1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
```

and the standard is:

```
<option value="Value1" selected>Option 1</option>
```

You may be able to do:

```
options[1].selected = true;
```